# How to parse each response using regex

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone help me parse these messages? These responses are from a TCP socket connection into a twitch channel chat. Sometimes the responses are one message, sometimes multiple, especially in hectic channels. Below you can see 1 response from using "response ---". The first 3 responses have 2 messages, the next three have 1, and the next two have multiple.

```
Response ----  :clonek1ng!clonek1ng@clonek1ng.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :ring them up
:bungus!bungus@bungus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :karma for laughing at the dancing guy FeelsBadMan

Response ----  :ayaannnk!ayaannnk@ayaannnk.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :!emotes bttv
:534mus!534mus@534mus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip

Response ----  :billybuttcheek!billybuttcheek@billybuttcheek.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :H H H H H H
:pimppdaddyyy!pimppdaddyyy@pimppdaddyyy.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :OMEGALUL

Response ----  :koolaidjammer__!koolaidjammer__@koolaidjammer__.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqcHead xqcHead xqcHead

Response ----  :its_physikz!its_physikz@its_physikz.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqcSus BLOW PIPES?

Response ----  :syon_!syon_@syon_.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip ONLY 40?

Response ----  :maybehzrdus!maybehzrdus@maybehzrdus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :MARIJUANA
:choomoo__!choomoo__@choomoo__.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :HOW IS THERAPY BATCHEST OMEGALUL
:logicalforce!logicalforce@logicalforce.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :LULW
:z3rgling!z3rgling@z3rgling.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip NICE
:skuup0p!skuup0p@skuup0p.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :H GG

Response ----  :tnr_gio!tnr_gio@tnr_gio.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :mothakeeeeee
:vajinablender!vajinablender@vajinablender.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqKaren IM STRESSIN BRUH
:logic_al!logic_al@logic_al.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :i'll smoke to that
:axelblaze1755!axelblaze1755@axelblaze1755.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :madafeh PepegaPls madh PepegaPls madafuPepegaPls madaPepegaPls mada PepegaPls
:neamzz!neamzz@neamzz.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :FeelsBadMan
```

I was thinking since each message in a response has two ":" I was thinking separating the string by every two ":" using regex. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple str methods

```
spam = """Response ----  :clonek1ng!clonek1ng@clonek1ng.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :ring them up
:bungus!bungus@bungus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :karma for laughing at the dancing guy FeelsBadMan

Response ----  :ayaannnk!ayaannnk@ayaannnk.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :!emotes bttv
:534mus!534mus@534mus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip

Response ----  :billybuttcheek!billybuttcheek@billybuttcheek.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :H H H H H H
:pimppdaddyyy!pimppdaddyyy@pimppdaddyyy.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :OMEGALUL

Response ----  :koolaidjammer__!koolaidjammer__@koolaidjammer__.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqcHead xqcHead xqcHead

Response ----  :its_physikz!its_physikz@its_physikz.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqcSus BLOW PIPES?

Response ----  :syon_!syon_@syon_.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip ONLY 40?

Response ----  :maybehzrdus!maybehzrdus@maybehzrdus.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :MARIJUANA
:choomoo__!choomoo__@choomoo__.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :HOW IS THERAPY BATCHEST OMEGALUL
:logicalforce!logicalforce@logicalforce.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :LULW
:z3rgling!z3rgling@z3rgling.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :CiGrip NICE
:skuup0p!skuup0p@skuup0p.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :H GG

Response ----  :tnr_gio!tnr_gio@tnr_gio.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :mothakeeeeee
:vajinablender!vajinablender@vajinablender.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :xqKaren IM STRESSIN BRUH
:logic_al!logic_al@logic_al.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :i'll smoke to that
:axelblaze1755!axelblaze1755@axelblaze1755.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :madafeh PepegaPls madh PepegaPls madafuPepegaPls madaPepegaPls mada PepegaPls
:neamzz!neamzz@neamzz.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #xqcow :FeelsBadMan
"""


for response in spam.replace('Response ----  ', '').split('\n\n'):
    print(response.strip().splitlines())
```

you get messages in each response as lists. You can work from here if you don't care if message came from different response